# Verify integration of function / PDE check

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Given that for some function $u(x,t)$, if $u_{txt} = 4x$, then $u(x,t) = x^2 t^2 + A(t) + B(x)$.

So, I integrate backwards and seem to get stuck:

1. I first integrate with respect to t, and get: $4xt + B(x)$.
2. Then, I integrate with respect to x, and get: $2x^2 t + b(x)$, where $b(x) = \int B(x) dx$.
3. Now, I integrate with respect to t again, and get: $x^2  t^2 + A(x) + \int b(x) dt$, which is $x^2 t^2 + A(x) + t b(x)$ plus another constant. I don't know how to resolve the $t b(x)$ term, but everything else matches.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I keep getting, I suppose my prof's lecture notes were incorrect then, leaving off the tC(x).